# Wordpress search function returning css code snippets

Tags: wordpress, search

Hi I have updated my Wordpress theme and the search function seems to not function correctly anymore. I am typing in search terms and some of the results come back as css code snippets which seems to be from my rev slider styling. The article title is still displaying correctly but the summary is just code.

I would appreciate it if someone could take a quick look if it's something simple to fix/figure out.

This is the website and the search functionality is on the blog page

http://fleetoperations.o2clite.com/blog/

P.S. I have also contacted the theme devs, but they are quite slow to reply.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this thread: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ajaxsearchlite-only-css-shows-up-for-image-gallery-search-results

Comment: Hi and thanks, but unfortunately this is not relevant as 1. I do not have a search plugin installed, 2. I'm not trying to search for images, but content. I can't use it to solve my problem

Comment: Yes, I know but similar preg_replace could do the job. What about backup? Isn't it possible to compare the files?